# Not able to automate using appium for android version 7.1.2 (Redmi 4)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I am running automation on android real devices. The automation works successfully across devices which has version less than 7. But when I try to run automation on devices which has version greater than 7(Redmi-note4, Redmi 4), I am getting a below error.

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\sandeepraju\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-819864143\testng-customsuite.xml

FAILED: newRegistrationIn
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "C:\Users\sandeepraju\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb.exe shell "stop; sleep 2; setprop sys.boot_completed 0; start""
stop: must be root
start: must be root
) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 9.96 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'SandeepDell', ip: '192.168.234.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:109)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:39)
    at com.gdi.basemodule.LaunchApp.launchApplication(LaunchApp.java:51)
    at com.gdi.modules.Modules.newRegistrationIn(Modules.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Please refer the below code.

```
    public  AndroidDriver launchApplication(String appName,ExtentTest testReport) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException 

{
        DesiredCapabilities cap= new DesiredCapabilities();
        File appDir=new File("apps");
        File app= new File(appDir,appName);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION,"6.0.1");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Redmi4");
        AndroidDriver androidDriver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
        System.out.println(androidDriver);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "100");
        androidDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        testReport.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Launch application");
        if(androidDriver!=null) 
        {
            testReport.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Successfully launched the application");
        }
}
```

Please help me to run my automation android real devices 7.0

Comment: Update your Appium.  The problem was well-known for quite some time, but they apparently finally fixed it not too long ago.  I had the same problem and had to restrict all my tests to API's < 7 but now it runs on all API's without any code changes.

Comment: Thanks it worked after installing appium version 1.7.1

Comment: I've got to start answering as an answer instead of a comment so I can get credit when my answers work! :)  Glad I could help.

Comment: I'm going to post my comment as an answer so that you can mark it as the solution, if you don't mind.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Appium. The problem was well-known for quite some time, but they apparently finally fixed it not too long ago. I had the same problem and had to restrict all my tests to API's < 7 but now it runs on all API's without any code changes.